# My app keep the device awake all the time

Tags: java, android

I have a major problem with my app, my phone complains about my app saying it uses a lot of battery.

After checking the app power consumption i saw this:

```
CPU total -------------- 13m 27s
Keep awake ------------- 10h 22m 58s
Data received ---------- 80
Data sent -------------- 87
Mobile radio active ---- 1m 14s
Computed power use ----- 375 mAh
```

I'm not so sure what to check in my app,
my app uses firebase for push notifications, admob, fabric crashlytics

Can anyone aim me to the right direction please?

Here is some of my manifest file:

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" /> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/appThemDark">
    <service android:name="com.blabla.Classes.Firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.blabla.Classes.Firebase.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
...
```

Here is a method profiling by Android device monitor, it was taken about 4 minutes after i locked my device without any interruptions

[image: Method Profile]

Thanks!

Comment: post manifest file

Comment: Active can mean background activity. Maybe post your background service to be sure?

Comment: I have added the main part of my manifest

Comment: you have other services in your app?

Comment: Not that i know of

Comment: maybe you keep the camera active all the time or do you use any wakelocks which you eventually do not release properly?

Comment: I don't think i have used wakelock, since i haven't heard about it before, though, what should i search for to make sure i really didn't used one?